# Why can't I use LinkedList::new?

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

Let's say I have a HashMap as `Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();`.

Now `List<Integer> values = computeIfAbsent(key, ArrayList::new);` works perfectly but `List<Integer> values = computeIfAbsent(key, LinkedList::new);` throws compilation error.

I can see no-arg constructors in both ArrayList as well as LinkedList. 
What am I missing here,can someone explain this behavior ?

Comment: "throws compilation error", usually, readying set error gives you the first clue. what does it say?

Comment: Are you import java.util.*;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The needed lambda must be of signature `Function<? super K,? extends V> mappingFunction`, so when you write:

```
List<Integer> values = map.computeIfAbsent(key, ArrayList::new);
```

a constructor with an argument of a type compatible with the one of `key` (`Integer`) must be given. There is one for `ArrayList` but no for `LinkedList`:

Constructors for `ArrayList`:

> ArrayList()
>
> ArrayList(Collection c)
>
> ArrayList(int initialCapacity)

Constructors for `LinkedList`:

> LinkedList()
>
> LinkedList(Collection c)

**Becareful** that the fact that it works for `ArrayList` is probably not a good point as it constructs an empty `ArrayList` with an initial capacity (which may lead to strange border effects).

You may refer to [Method reference in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

Comment: It’s important to emphasize that the `ArrayList(int)` constructor implicitly used in the `computeIfAbsent(key, ArrayList::new)` example is not doing the intended thing and may lead to surprising `OutOfMemoryError`s.

Answer (score 7):

What you probably intend to do is specify the lamba expression for initialisation as :

```
List<Integer> values = map.computeIfAbsent(key, a -> new ArrayList<>());
```

or

```
List<Integer> values = map.computeIfAbsent(key, a -> new LinkedList<>());
```

---

The reason, why the code

```
List<Integer> values = computeIfAbsent(key, LinkedList::new);
```

wouldn't compile is that the constructor closest to the current syntax with a single argument expects a `Collection<? extends E> c` instead of an `Integer`, hence it could not be resolved.

On the other hand, the reason why

```
List<Integer> values = map.computeIfAbsent(key, ArrayList::new);
```

compiles is, it has a [constructor accepting `int` argument](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#%3Cinit%3E(int)), **but do note** its for the capacity of the list.

Comment: @AmitBera True. Updated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use following command

```
List<Integer> values = map.computeIfAbsent(key, x -> new ArrayList<>());
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained why.